# (undefined method `vote_exclusively_for' for nil:NilClass) when user is logged out, but not when logged in - Rails 3 (thumbs_up gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using `gem thumbs_up`

My Upload model has the required code:

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_voteable
```

The model that is doing the voting, the Client, also has the other side:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_voter
```

My `uploads_controller` looks like this:

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:vote_up, :vote_down]
def vote_up
        begin
           (current_user || @client_user).vote_exclusively_for(@upload = Upload.find(params[:id]))
          render :nothing => true, :status => 200
        rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
          render :nothing => true, :status => 404
        end
      end

        def vote_down
            begin
             (current_user || @client_user).vote_exclusively_against(@upload = Upload.find(params[:id]))
                render :nothing => true, :status => 200
            rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
                render :nothing => true, :status => 404
            end
        end
end
```

The error I get is:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `vote_exclusively_for' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/uploads_controller.rb:75:in `vote_up'
```

Thoughts ?

Btw, not sure if this is relevant, but I have two models `Client` and `User` that have `acts_as_voter`.

Edit1: Applications Controller with `@client_user`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    def check_token_or_user

        stage = Stage.find(params[:id])
        client = stage.client
        client_access_key = client.authentication_token
        stage_access_key = stage.authentication_token

            if !user_signed_in? && params[:ck].blank? && params[:sk].blank?
          redirect_to(:login)
        elsif !user_signed_in? && params[:ck] == client_access_key && params[:sk] == stage_access_key
          # do nothing, they can view the page      
            elsif user_signed_in?
          # do nothing, they can view the page
            else
                redirect_to(root_path)
        end

    @client_user = Client.where(:authentication_token => client_access_key).first #have to specify which record, otherwise it will save the collection of users, hence the '.first'

    end
end
```

This is called in the `stages_controller` in a before filter like this:

```
before_filter :check_token_or_user, :only => :compare
```

Comment: In my application controller. Basically, I check to see if certain params are in the URL and if they are, I set `@client_user` as follows: `@client_user = Client.where(:authentication_token => client_access_key).first`...where `client_access_key` was one of the params in the URL - actually it is the value from the URL stored in a local variable...but you get the idea.

Comment: Hrmm...well when I put `debug(@client_user)` on the page, and it shows me the right @client_user.

Comment: I updated the question with my code snippet for my Application Controller with the @client_user code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that both current_user and @client_user are nil.

@client_user is never defined because method check_token_or_user is called only on action :compare, not your actions :vote_up or :vote_down

About current_user - it depends on how your authentication is implemented but I'd say that if authenticate_user! is not called, it will be nil as well. And authenticate_user! is definitely not called, because of the :except => [:vote_up, :vote_down] in the before_filter.

EDIT: So to solve this you have to add more actions to one of those before_filters so one of them could actually get called.

Comment: What if I told you, the action that the is being rendered - i.e. where the `uploads` are that can be voted on, is being called. Would that change your answer ? As in, the url is `stages/46/compare?p1=jsugkjeb` where a `before_filter` exists for that specific action like so: `before_filter :check_token_or_user, :only => :compare` So, the assumption basically is that since they are already on the `compare` action (as that is the only action where voting is allowed) the `@client_user` should be initialized and not be nil. Also, I added a `debug(@client_user)` and see that `@client_user` != Nil

Comment: For instance, this is the output of my `debug(@client_user)` `--- !ruby/object:Client 
attributes: 
  id: 62
  email: test@abc.com
  user_id: 1
  created_at: 2011-04-06 10:14:12.002169
  updated_at: 2011-04-06 10:14:12.002169
  authentication_token: rRC58oHa48WZlZFO2Fr_
attributes_cache: {}`

Which is right.

Comment: Mate, the error message you showed us clearly says that (current_user || @client_user) is nil, because you got message: undefined method `vote_exclusively_for' for nil:NilClass. Then both current_user and @client_user has to be nil. Make sure you placed the debug command at the right place so that the vote_up action gets called. Note that it does not matter what you render, the "current action" is the method that gets called in the controller whatever you render in it.

Comment: Ok...thanks...your response helped me narrow it down and get it. I eventually had to write a new `before_filter` but you definitely helped me narrow it down.